# How to identify which button was clicked

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a Button, Once the user submits a form the button image should change to `DONE.PNG`, or else it will remain as `SUBMIT.PNG`.

I need to know the following;

1.) How can we write a method, to know which button the user clicked. (If he clicked the button when it has the `DONE.PNG` or `SUBMIT.PNG` image on it)

my button click event is `-(void)buttonClicked : (id)sender {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using a single button and changing its image only, then there are two simple ways that you can follow:

1. Check the name of image of the button if its `DONE.PNG` then do what is required and change the image else vis-versa.
2. Have a variable either you can take integer(it will help you if you have even more number of image changes on same button) to track button state/image.

For example we will `typedef buttonState` and check against it for suitable case.

In `.h` file

//Before interface declaration..

```
typedef enum
{
   ButtonStateDone = 1,
   ButtonStateSubmit,
  //any other state that it may have.
} ButtonState
```

//in interface declaration..

`ButtonState buttonState;` //its a class level variable that we will use to track button state.

In `.m` file

Initially set buttonState as you show it on initial view. suppose button shows DONE.PNG
so `buttonState = ButtonStateDone;`

Now, in button action you will change this

```
if(buttonState == ButtonStateDone)
{
 //do something and change button state.
}
if(buttonState == ButtonStateSubmit)
{
 //do something and change button state.
}
```

Here, I used `typedef`, it is useful if you need to have more than 2 states for button else you can simply use a `BOOL` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would set the tag of the UIButton.

-Interface or storyboard you do it under the info about the UIButton element.

-Programatically you do it like this : myButton.tag = 23;

Then in the buttonClicked you do this:

```
UIButton* senderButton = (UIButton*) sender;
if(senderButton.tag==23) {
   // It's the button as submit
   // Set button image
   senderButton.tag = 5;
}
if(senderButton.tag==5) {
   // Button is done
}
```

Hope you get it working :)

Comment: Is there any other way i could do it without using Tags

Answer (score 0):

You can add a tag to the button i.e. NSInteger buttonTag = [sender tag] and then have conditional statements to check the tag values to determine which button was clicked.

Comment: Is there any other way i could do it without using Tags